# How to access vector in map

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;
class ship
{
    protected:
    string type;
    int size;
    int hits;
};
int main()
{
    map< char,vector<ship*> > board;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        vector<ship*> v;
        for(int j = 0;j<10;j++)

        {
            ship *s = new ship();
            v.push_back(s);
        }
        board['A'+i] = v;
    }//set board 
}
```

I made `map<char,vector<ship*> >` board. How can I access to `type` (in `ship` class) from first ship pointer in first element of vector in map?

Comment: *[c++][map][vector]* Don't do this. That's what tags are for.

Comment: First, you can't. `type` is protected and `main()` isn't friended. Second, `board['A'][0]->type` assuming you fix the first problem, but I strongly suspect a dark horizon. Best of luck.

Comment: `vector<ship*> v;`  -- Why are you using pointers here?  Why not just `vector<ship> v;` and skip all of the calls to `new`?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, maybe my answer will be a bit over the top, and it's not really what you ask, I know, but it could help you understand why values in ship are protected, and I have too much time it seems.

Since it's a very common problem to build a game around ships/monsters/objects that have a common base of methods and attributes, there is a very common way to implement this. It's based on a three level inheritance.

**1. Interface**

It will define what methods can be called from the outside, it's a contract. Every class that inherits from it **MUST** implement those methods.

In your case a basic one would look like this:

```
class IShip
{
    public:
        virtual ~IShip() // needs this, see link below
        { std::cout << "Interface destructor called" << std::endl; }

        virtual std::string type() = 0;
        virtual int         size() = 0;
        virtual int         hits() = 0;

        virtual void    specialMove() = 0;
};
```

[Reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3628611/6374665) for the virtual dtor.

**2. Abstract**

It inherits from this interface, and implement the basic methods that are re-usable by every ship, it could be done this way:

```
class AShip : public IShip
{
    public:
        AShip(std::string type, int size, int hits)
            : _type(type)
            , _size(size)
            , _hits(hits)
        { std::cout << "Abstract constructor called" << std::endl; }

        virtual ~AShip() // still needs this
        { std::cout << "Abstract destructor called" << std::endl; }

        virtual inline std::string type()   // inline keyword to put the code in-place instead of calling it
        { return _type; }                   // should only do this on very small methods

        virtual inline int size()           // virtual are not necessary
        { return _size; }                   // but it's best practice to clarify code

        virtual inline int hits()
        { return _hits; }

        // -- need overload method
        virtual void    specialMove() = 0;

    // -- protected since it needs to be accessible from child classes
    protected:
        std::string _type;
        int         _size;
        int         _hits;
};
```

At this point you can not instantiate anything because both those classes are virtual. [More about virtual classes](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_interfaces.htm)

An interface being a **pure virtual** class (because every methods defined have '= 0').

**3. Instanciable**

What you can do now is implement easily multiple classes that inherits from AShip but still specify something special, you are right, i'm talking about the **specialMove**, i'll create two classes for the sake of my example:

```
class TheDestructor : public AShip
{
    public:
        TheDestructor()
            : AShip("The Destructor", 20, 100)
            , _attack("DestructionOver9000")
        { std::cout << "TheDestructor constructor called" << std::endl; }

        virtual ~TheDestructor() // still needs this to help the compiler
        { std::cout << "TheDestructor destructor called" << std::endl; }

        inline void specialMove() // specialMove overload
        { std::cout << "Attack " << _attack << " from " << _type << std::endl; }

    private:
        std::string _attack;
};

class MyPunyShip : public AShip
{
    public:
        MyPunyShip()
            : AShip("My Puny Ship", 1, 1)
            , _escape("just fly away as fast as he can...")
        { std::cout << "MyPunyShip constructor called" << std::endl; }

        virtual ~MyPunyShip() // still needs this to help the compiler
        { std::cout << "MyPunyShip destructor called" << std::endl; }

        inline void specialMove() // specialMove overload
        { std::cout << _type << " " << _escape << std::endl; }

    private:
        std::string _escape;
};
```

Now let us test what has been done:

```
int     main()
{
    std::map<std::string, IShip*>   ships;

    ships.insert(std::make_pair("The Destructor", new TheDestructor));
    std::cout << std::endl;
    ships.insert(std::make_pair("My Puny Ship", new MyPunyShip));
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for (std::map<std::string, IShip*>::iterator itS = ships.begin() ; itS != ships.end() ; ++itS)
    {
        // *itS to access the data of the iterator
        // second to access the second member of the pair
        std::cout << "type: " << (*itS).second->type() << "\n";
        std::cout << "size: " << (*itS).second->size() << "\n";
        std::cout << "hits: " << (*itS).second->hits() << "\n";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    ships["The Destructor"]->specialMove();
    ships["My Puny Ship"]->specialMove();
}
```

You can only call the methods that are in the interface, because the type in the map is an IShip, but it allows you to implement various ships with different stats.

let's see that output...

**Output:**

```
Abstract constructor called
TheDestructor constructor called

Abstract constructor called
MyPunyShip constructor called

type: My Puny Ship - size: 1 - hits: 1

type: The Destructor - size: 20 - hits: 100

Attack DestructionOver9000 from The Destructor
My Puny Ship just fly away as fast as he can...
```

But, but... Something is missing right?
Something seems very odd... What??? I forgot to use delete??

Well, I forgot to use c++11 as a whole to make the example a bit smaller and to keep what I was trying to convey clear. What I should have used here is [std::unique_ptr](http://fr.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) or [std::shared_ptr](http://fr.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

The 'new' main would look like this and compile with c++11 flag enabled:

```
int     main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<IShip>>   ships;

    ships.emplace(std::make_pair("The Destructor", std::shared_ptr<IShip>(new TheDestructor)));
    ships.emplace(std::make_pair("My Puny Ship", std::shared_ptr<IShip>(new MyPunyShip)));

    for (auto ship : ships) // damn that's neat...
    {
        std::cout << "type: " << ship.second->type() << " - ";
        std::cout << "size: " << ship.second->size() << " - ";
        std::cout << "hits: " << ship.second->hits() << "\n";
    }

    ships["The Destructor"]->specialMove();
    ships["My Puny Ship"]->specialMove();
}
```

**Output:**

```
Abstract constructor called
TheDestructor constructor called

Abstract constructor called
MyPunyShip constructor called

type: My Puny Ship - size: 1 - hits: 1
type: The Destructor - size: 20 - hits: 100

Attack DestructionOver9000 from The Destructor

My Puny Ship just fly away as fast as he can...

TheDestructor destructor called
Abstract destructor called
Interface destructor called
MyPunyShip destructor called
Abstract destructor called
Interface destructor called
```

Wow, I missed you so much c++11. Joke apart, you can see that the destructors are automatically called for our IShip* pointers, pretty nice if you ask me.

Why both Interface and Abstract, seems like overdoing it? My take on this is that one could need a IVehicle but create AShip, ACar, ASpaceCraft etc... with different limitations. But it's a very valid question, and you should adapt this "pattern" to fit your needs and your philosophy.

Hope it can help you understand a few concepts on c++/c++11 and inheritance, next step for you is to build a [factory](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/factory_method/cpp/1) ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since `type` is declared as `protected`, you can't normally access that. `protected` members are only accessible by `friend` classes or those who inherit from the class. The easiest solution is to declare the variables as `public`. But it has its own caveats.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should declare `type` as `public`.

Then, you should do `board[index].front()->type`

**Important:** the `index` should be a `char` variable, since the type of the key of the map `board` is `char`.

example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;
class ship
{
    public:
    string type;
    int size;
    int hits;
};
int main()
{
    map< char, vector<ship*> > board;
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
    {
        vector<ship*> v;
        for (int j = 0; j<10; j++)
        {
            ship *s = new ship();
            s->type = "Cannon ship";
            v.push_back(s);
        }
        board['A' + i] = v;
    }//set board 
    cout << board['A'].front()->type << endl;
}
```

Comment: It's a matter of personal taste, but I prefer to declare `ship` as `struct` since it has no methods here. Then you won't need the `public` keyword. Also in `for` loop you can combine the three lines as: `v.push_back(new ship{"Cannon ship"});`