# Special case of "Delete called on base class that is abstract but has non-virtual destructor"

Tags: c++, warnings, abstract-class, destructor

This is a minimal reproducable example matching my setup :

(using Qt, but the `QList` can easily be replaced with any kind of `std` container I guess)

```
class DataType
{

};

class DerivedDataType : public DataType
{

};

class OtherDerivedDataType : public DataType
{

};

class AbstractDataContainer
{
public :

    ~AbstractDataContainer() { for(DataType* pData : qAsConst(dataList)) { delete pData; } };
    virtual void insertData() = 0;

protected:

    AbstractDataContainer() {};
    QList<DataType*> dataList;
};

template<class T>
class DataContainer : public AbstractDataContainer
{
public:
    DataContainer() : AbstractDataContainer() {};
    ~DataContainer() {};

    void insertData() {DataType* pData = new T(); dataList.append(pData);}
};

void main(void)
{
    QList<AbstractDataContainer*> listOfAbstractDataContainers;
    listOfAbstractDataContainers.append(new DataContainer<DerivedDataType>());
    listOfAbstractDataContainers.append(new DataContainer<OtherDerivedDataType>());

    for(AbstractDataContainer* pAbstractDataContainer : qAsConst(listOfAbstractDataContainers))
    {
        pAbstractDataContainer->insertData();
    }

     /*... do stuff ... */

    /* Finish : clean up. */
    for(AbstractDataContainer* pAbstractDataContainer : qAsConst(listOfAbstractDataContainers))
    {
        delete pAbstractDataContainer;
    }
}
```

I get the warning "Delete called on base class 'AbstractDataContainer' that is abstract but has non-virtual destructor". Should I be worried ? Am I doing something wrong ? is there an equivalent way of doing what I do without getting this error ?

I only differentiated between `AbstractDataContainer` and `DataContainer` because it is not possible to create a list of templated classes without knowing how each element of the container is going to be templated, given that I want every element of the container to have different template arguments, yet still be able to iterate in a generic/polymorphic way over all elements of the container without going into `switch`es for each type of data. At least this is the case with `QList` and the like in Qt : you cannot write this :

```
QList<const template<class T> DataContainer> listOfDataContainers;
listOfDataContainers.append(DataContainer<DerivedDataType>);
listOfDataContainers.append(DataContainer<OtherDerivedDataType>);
```

Comment: `~AbstractDataContainer` should be `virtual`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/461203/10362622 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/3628529/10362622

Comment: The destructor need to be virtual. I don't understand what "special" in the title refers to, how is this special or different from any other question you may find by searching this error message?

Comment: Okay it compiles with the destructor being `virtual` even though `DataContainer` does not override the destructor. I though it wouldn't even compile. in that case. What's the difference in behavior though now that the destructor is virtual ?

Comment: If you `delete` a polymorphic type type via pointer to the base class, the destructor needs to be `virtual` in order for the correct destructor to run.

Comment: you dont have override the destructor, it is sufficient to inherit it. i guess also `DataType` should have a virtual destructor

Comment: @JesperJuhl I know but "the correct destructor to run" is a non-issue in my case, since all the data is in the base class. The derived class is only there for the templated "insert" method. I want the compiler to not ask questions here and go straight to the base class destructor, always.

Comment: @charles That doesn't change the fact that it is [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) to delete a type via pointer to base if the destructor is not virtual.

Comment: things already do work like you wish: If a class has no members then its destructor does nothing, and base class destructors are called, but nevertheless its wrong to not call the proper destructor. You cannot freely choose, and you dont have to.

Comment: Yes I was just reading that - it's undefined always and everywhere (not just when there are multiple derived classes with different destructoras). Okay then I shall oblige.

Comment: I guess yes ! I mean it basically says what we've been hashing out in this comment section.